# fullscreen popup in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a popup window fullscreen, completely fullscreen, no borders.
I've found scripts (a great one by [David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen)) that set the current page or any element on the page to fullscreen, but I can't get them to work on a popup window.

The limitation is that you can't go fullscreen without the users approval, so he or she must click, but it seems that that "approval" does not carry over to a new window.

Is there a way to carry over this approval or get the new window fullscreen?

I'm leaning towards no and I'm thinking of implementing a way with a hidden div on the page that loads content on focus via ajax or iframe (just brainstorming not tested yet).

Comment: I am doing a pure guess, but can you put this code for approval in new window already, so some action -> new window -> alert Please approve full screen -> than it should work since it's the same window.

Comment: Yes, I could but that would mean an extra click for the user, which is undesirable and the popups are all different pages, literally hundreds, so I would have to change those all, plus pages are added constantly by others and they would have to add this and I'm not sure they can as those are not always the most techsavy people. Where as the page where I open the popups is a list of links which is generated by PHP, so there I would only have to change a few lines of code.

Comment: I read it now more carefully, I don't know if you really need to mass pop up windows, if at one time you don't need multiple windows than iframe it's better ( you can even add some tools to that "service" page, like save this page, make a screenshot or something + option hide tools etc.).